# Run command / script after build

Tags: angular

I have created a batch file that uploads the files in my `dist` folder to another directory. Is there a way I can run the batch file when `ng build` has completed?

Answer (score 0):

Write a simple `js` script for this in a file `runner.js`

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');
 exec('my.bat', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (err) {
   console.error(err);
   return;
 }
 console.log(stdout);
});
```

and write a script in `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
  "postbuild": "node runner.js",
}
```

more info [here](https://gist.github.com/coryhouse/b7ff5e6d1e41b762c35b)

Answer (score 0):

In your `package.json`, you can call your script to run after the `build` in `postbuild`.

```
{
  "name": "npm-scripts-example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "npm scripts example",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "ng build --base-href / --prod",
    "postbuild": "node ./scripts/runafterbuild.js"
  }
```